# Prove constrained problem has no duality gap

Tags: proof-explanation, duality-theorems

For an exam I have to prove that if a constrained problem has no duality gap for some $(l,g)$ and $x$, then $x$ is a global minimum point for the constrained problem. Do you think an example is sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

No, example would not be sufficient for a general proof. Just because this is true for your example, does not mean it is generally true.